# change - to + in Common Lisp

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

Is there way to change `-` (minus) function to `+` (plus) function?

My homework is to implement sin calculation on Macluaurin series

```
sin(x) = x-(x^3/3!)+(x^5/5!) -(x^7/7!)+(x^9/9!)-...
```

Each article has different sign. This is my Lisp code

```
(defun sinMac (x series n plusminus)
  (cond ((= series 0) 0)
        (t (funcall plusminus
                    (/ (power x n) (factorial n))
                    (sinMac x (- series 1) (+ n 2) plusminus)))))
```

Is it possible to change `plusminus` to exchange sign? if I get `'+` function send `'-` to next recursive call. From that call (got `'-`) I call `'+` and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a circular list. Like so:

```
(defun sin-mac (x series n plus-minus)
  (cond ((zerop series) 0)
        (t (funcall (car plus-minus)
                    (/ (power x n) (factorial n))
                    (sin-mac x (1- series) (+ n 2) (cdr plus-minus))))))

(sin-mac x series 1 '#0=(+ - . #0#))
```

Or even better, wrap up the initial arguments using `labels`:

```
(defun sin-mac (x series)
  (labels ((recur (series n plus-minus)
             (cond ((zerop series) 0)
                   (t (funcall (car plus-minus)
                               (/ (power x n) (factorial n))
                               (recur (1- series) (+ n 2) (cdr plus-minus)))))))
    (recur series 1 '#0=(+ - . #0#))))
```

Answer (score 3):

If the function is a symbol, this is easy:

```
(defun next-function (function)
  (ecase function
    (+ '-)
    (- '+)))

(defun sinMac (x series n plusminus)
  (cond ((= series 0) 0)
        (t (funcall plusminus
                    (/ (power x n) (factorial n))
                    (sinMac x
                            (- series 1)
                            (+ n 2)
                            (next-function plusminus))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not swap the function but just the sign.  Using a loop for this also seems clearer to me (and is most likely more efficient, although there is still plenty of opportunity for optimization):

```
(defun maclaurin-sinus (x n)
  "Calculates the sinus of x by the Maclaurin series of n elements."
  (loop :for i :below n
    :for sign := 1 :then (- sign)
    :sum (let ((f (1+ (* 2 i))))
           (* sign
              (/ (expt x f)
                 (factorial f))))))
```

A few optimizations make this about 10 times faster (tested with *n = 5*):

```
(defun maclaurin-sinus-optimized (x n)
  "Calculates the sinus of x by the Maclaurin series of n elements."
  (declare (integer n))
  (loop :repeat n
    :for j :from 0 :by 2
    :for k :from 1 :by 2
    :for sign := 1 :then (- sign)
    :for e := x :then (* e x x)
    :for f := 1 :then (* f j k)
    :sum (/ e f sign)))
```